# The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation

Tags: angular-cli

Been getting this error when running 'ng build' on my Angular 12.0.2 project

```
./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
    at getCompilationHooks (D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:125:10)
    at D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\CommonJsChunkFormatPlugin.js:43:19
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1030:30)
    at D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1073:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.compile (D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1068:28)
    at Compiler.runAsChild (D:\Dev\Git_Merc\mercury\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:520:8)
```

I've been googling around but can't find anything that solves my issue.  I'm not sure what's triggering this.

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 12.0.2
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 7.14.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.0.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1200.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     12.0.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1200.2
@angular-devkit/core              12.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        12.0.2
@angular/cli                      12.0.2
@schematics/angular               12.0.2
ng-packagr                        12.0.2
rxjs                              7.1.0
typescript                        4.2.4
webpack                           5.38.0
```

---

### Update 1 - adding requested information from @Heretic Monkey

The command I'm running is `ng build`.

My `angular.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Agent-Angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Agent-Angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@mercury/merc-pattern-lib/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "nonprod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.nonprod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Agent-Angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "Agent-Angular:build:local"
            },
            "nonprod": {
              "browserTarget": "Agent-Angular:build:nonprod"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Agent-Angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Agent-Angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Agent-Angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Agent-Angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cee-ctilib": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/cee-ctilib",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/cee-ctilib/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/cee-ctilib/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/cee-ctilib/ng-package.json"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/cee-ctilib/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/cee-ctilib/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/cee-ctilib/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/cee-ctilib/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/cee-ctilib/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "entities": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/entities",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/entities/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/entities/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/entities/ng-package.json"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/entities/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/entities/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/entities/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/entities/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/entities/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Agent-Angular",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
  }
}
```

---

### Update 2 - adding package.json

```
{
  "name": "agent-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Mercury Chat Application",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "format:src": "prettier --config ./prettier.config.js --ignore-path ./.prettierignore --write \"src/**/*.\"{ts,js,json,scss,less,css}",
    "format:projects": "prettier --config ./prettier.config.js --ignore-path ./.prettierignore --write \"projects/**/*.\"{ts,js,json,scss,less,css}",
    "format:e2e": "prettier --config ./prettier.config.js --ignore-path ./.prettierignore --write \"e2e/**/*.\"{ts,js,json,scss,less,css}",
    "format:root": "prettier --config ./prettier.config.js --ignore-path ./.prettierignore --write \"*.\"{ts,js,json,scss,less,css}",
    "format:all": "npm run format:src && npm run format:projects && npm run format:e2e && npm run format:root",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start": "npm run && ng serve --prod",
    "build": "npm run && ng build --prod --base-href=./",
    "build:dev": "npm run && ng build",
    "unit:test": "ng test",
    "unit:test:main": "ng test Agent-Angular --code-coverage",
    "unit:test:entities": "ng test entities --code-coverage",
    "unit:test:cee-ctilib": "ng test cee-ctilib --code-coverage",
    "unit:test:debug": "ng test --browsers Chrome --watch true",
    "unit:test:entities:debug": "ng test entities --browsers Chrome --watch true",
    "start:local": "ng serve -c local --host local.mercury.comcast.net  --port 443 --ssl --ssl-key ./cert/local.mercury.comcast.net.key --ssl-cert ./cert/local.mercury.comcast.net.crt",
    "start:dev": "ng serve -c dev --host dev.mercury.comcast.net  --port 443 --ssl --ssl-key ./cert/localhost.key --ssl-cert ./cert/localhost.crt",
    "build:cti": "ng-packagr -p ./projects/cee-ctilib/ng-package.json && cd ./dist && npm pack ./cee-ctilib",
    "build:header": "ng-packagr -p ./projects/header/ng-package.json && cd ./dist && npm pack ./header",
    "build:convo-header": "ng-packagr -p ./projects/convo-header/ng-package.json && cd ./dist && npm pack ./convo-header",
    "build:convo-details": "ng-packagr -p ./projects/convo-details/ng-package.json && cd ./dist && npm pack ./convo-details",
    "build:convo-list": "ng-packagr -p ./projects/convo-list/ng-package.json && cd ./dist && npm pack ./convo-list",
    "build:convo-window": "ng-packagr -p ./projects/convo-window/ng-package.json && cd ./dist && npm pack ./convo-window",
    "build:agent-settings": "ng-packagr -p ./projects/agent-settings/ng-package.json && cd ./dist && npm pack ./agent-settings",
    "build:entities": "ng-packagr -p ./projects/entities/ng-package.json && cd ./dist && npm pack ./entities",
    "build:all-libraries": "npm run build:cti && npm run build:header && npm run build:convo-header && npm run build:convo-details && npm run build:convo-list && npm run build:convo-window && npm run build:agent-settings && npm run build:entities",
    "refreshNpmrc": "vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc",
    "prepareForPr": "ng lint --fix && ng build --prod && ng test"
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "12.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "12.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "12.0.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.12.1",
    "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^5.1.0",
    "@jsier/retrier": "^1.2.4",
    "@mercury/merc-ng-core": "^5.1.0",
    "@mercury/merc-pattern-lib": "^2.11.0",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.5.11",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.6",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^12.0.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^12.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^12.0.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-quill": "^13.2.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.11",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "1.16.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-placeholder-module": "^0.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.0.1",
    "ts-retry": "^2.3.1",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "vsts-npm-auth": "^0.41.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1200.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.0.1",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^12.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/deep-freeze": "^0.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "deep-freeze": "^0.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-json-test-reporter": "1.0.0-beta",
    "jasmine-marbles": "0.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-json-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-typescript-es6-transform": "^5.5.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "mockdate": "^3.0.5",
    "ng-packagr": "^12.0.0",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
    "rxjs-marbles": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.4.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.37.1"
  },
  "author": "Mercury Team",
  "license": ""
}
```

Comment: Please show the command you are running and the contents of your angular.json file.

Comment: Can you also attach your package.json file? I had the same issue, and for me it was something with the beta webpack-5 storybook packages. This is most likely a dependency that is not playing well with webpack-5

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We figured it out.  As you can see in our `packages.json`, we have a dependency on `webpack`.  It seems `angular-devkit/build-angular` does as well.  We believe this created the known issue of multiple webpacks colliding and causing issues.  Removing our dependency on `webpack` fixed the issue.

Comment: You can keep your dependency to `webpack` but keep in mind its version must match the version required by `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. I had the very same problem even though my versions matched and what helped me was [npm dedupe](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-dedupe) command which flattened my `node_modules` by leaving only one `webpack` copy.

Comment: npm dedupe worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Yep, the issue is related to the 2 different webpack libs.
To resolve that add in to your package.json the next block:

```
 "resolutions": {
        "webpack": "5.41.1"
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, 2 different webpack versions was exactly my problem on a Rails project. Using `@rails/webpacker@6.0.0-rc.5` forces me to use `webpack@5.52.0`.

Comment: Thanks! After trying so many things, this solved the issue for me. In my case it was version '5.75.0', deduced from 'npm ls webpack'.

Comment: This solution did work for me, but I was actually able to remove the resolution by deleting `node_modules/` and my lock file, then re-installing my dependencies (without the resolution) so the lock file regenerated.

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was wrong path.

I ran the command from git Bash with wrong camelCase letters.

like: `c://Dev/Product`
instead of: `c://dev/Product`

**Fixed the path and it works.**

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in "running ng" test on Angular 13.

```
"dependencies": {
   "ngx-build-plus": "^13.0.1",              // requires webpack 5.70.0
.....
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.2.4", // requires webpack 5.67.0 
--> 
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.3.0", // requires webpack 5.70.0
```

This usually occurs when webpack is a dependency of multiple packages. Locking inside the package-lock.json and searching for "webpack" dependencies was my way to go. "npm dedupe " can sometimes resolve such issues.

Comment: npm dedupe worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the other answers to this question, I realized that the webpack version conflict was the problem.

#### Investigation

I tried adding a `resolution` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68386322/2102114), but that didn't work.

I saw that I had a dependency on webpack `^5.6.7` in my package.json, so now I needed to find which dependencies have a conflict with that.

So I ran this command to find out which of my dependencies have a hard dependency on webpack i.e. specify the exact major or minor version without `^` or `~`

```
cd node_modules

# Find all package.json files and look for '"webpack":' line which shows the dependency
# Print the file name as well as the webpack version line so its easy to find out which dependency has the issue

find . -name package.json | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo {} && grep '\"webpack\":' {}" | grep -B1 webpack
```

I realized from the above that I had dependencies that had something like `webpack: 4.x` and hence were conflicting.

#### Solution

Removing the webpack dependency from the package.json fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

in my case , upgrading node to 16.14.2 works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add an additional answer to this problem, because the accepted answer actually didn't work for my particular case.

I have an angular library project and as one should know, angular library projects have usually the following structure:

```
package.json
projects/my-lib/package.json
```

The project was working fine until angular 11, but after upgrading to angular 13, I started getting the same error mentioned by the OP when trying to run tests (oddly, the issue was only when running tests):

```
The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
```

I checked all dependencies for webpack versions and it was matching the version everywhere. I lost almost two weeks searching for answer and none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

Finally, I noticed that both package.json pointed to the very same dependency:

```json
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.9",
```

In a wild guess, I thought that MAYBE having it installed both in the parent and the child could cause angular builder to mix up something and so I removed from the sub project. And that was it. The tests started working again.

Lesson: when you have an angular library project, always check both package.json and prefer to avoid duplicate dependencies. It might bite you.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, however for Angular `15.2.2` and the storybook `6.5.16`.

You will need to specify the webpack version in your `package.json` to match the version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular`

use `npm ls webpack` and look for its direct match when adding it to you `package.json`

Don't use `"webpack": "^x.xx.x"` with the `^` cause it might pick a newer version and you have the same problem.

For my specific version webpack had to be set to: `"webpack": "5.75.0"`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue occurred when I installed webpack & webpack-cli on a package in my monorepo.

I fixed it by going to the root of the monorepo and running `yarn install`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue with Angular `16.0.2` and storybook `6.5.16`. The `npm dedupe webpack` command did not resolve my issue.

After running `npm ls webpack`, I did recognize that storybook depended on a different webpack version. [npm ls webpack results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCybl.png) So, I added the version which was specified in the @angular-devkit section of the results, `"webpack": "5.80.0"`, to the package.json file (in the Dependancies section) [addition to package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgvFK.png).

Answer (score 0):

in my case, [yarn-upgrade-all](https://yarnpkg.com/package/yarn-upgrade-all) has solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case was because the multiple webpack installations in order o fix a run the next command

```
npm ls webpack
```

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.6
| +-- @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1502.6
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- @ngtools/webpack@15.2.6
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- babel-loader@9.1.2
| | `-- webpack@5.76.1 deduped
| +-- copy-webpack-plugin@11.0.0
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- css-loader@6.7.3
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- less-loader@11.1.0
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- mini-css-extract-plugin@2.7.2
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- postcss-loader@7.0.2
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- sass-loader@13.2.0
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- source-map-loader@4.0.1 
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- webpack-dev-middleware@6.0.1
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- webpack-dev-server@4.11.1
| | +-- webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
| | | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| +-- webpack-subresource-integrity@5.1.0
| | +-- html-webpack-plugin@5.5.1
| | | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| `-- webpack@5.76.1
|   `-- terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.7
|     `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
+-- @storybook/angular@7.0.7
| +-- @storybook/builder-webpack5@7.0.7
| | +-- babel-loader@9.1.2
| | | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| | +-- fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@7.3.0
| | | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| | +-- style-loader@3.3.2
| | | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| | +-- webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
| | | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| | `-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
| `-- webpack@5.80.0
`-- babel-loader@8.2.5
`-- webpack@5.80.0 deduped
```

Then I added this override in package.json

```
 "overrides": {
     "webpack": "5.80.0"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case I was not using multiple versions of Webpack, and was seeing the issue even after running upgrades. Looking at the code there were a few mentions of 'HotModuleReplacement' which called the module that was throwing the error

In the Webpack.config file under PLUGINS I had the following set

new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()

I commented out that line and all the issues went away. Still not really sure of the underlying cause, but if you get the error its worth trying this as it may be an easy fix.

Answer (score -3):

prolly a terrible solution but i went to node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:227 and deleted this line

```
    if (!(compilation instanceof Compilation)) {
        throw new TypeError(
            "The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation"
        );
    }
```

and it seems to work now.